# adjust color, size and type of marker after data has been plotted in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, traits

I've plotted a bunch of scatter points then redraw the canvas:

```
self.display_points = ax.scatter(x,y)
wx.CallAfter(self.display.canvas.draw)
```

I have an object which contains the color. If this is changed by the user from the GUI, I want to be able to change the color of the points without having to replot the data.

```
def _color_changed(self):
    if hasattr(self, '_display_points'): 
        self._display_points.set_facecolors(self.color)
        wx.CallAfter(self.display.canvas.draw)
```

how is this done for the size of the marker and the type of marker... ie. what should `X` be in `_display_points.set_X` to change each of the plotted components. Is there somewhere these attributes can be found? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scatter` returns a [`PathCollection`](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection) object, which you can see has a relatively limited api for setting things after the fact.  The `Collection` family of classes trades the ability to update later for more efficient drawing.

If you are not using scatter's ability to set the size and color of each point separately you are much better off using

```
self.display_points, = ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle='none')
```

which will give you a `Line2D` object back and look identical your scatter plot.   `Line2D` has a much more flexible [api](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) which includes `set_marker` and `set_markersize`.